# CS:GO Private Matches

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

If my friend and I wanted to see who was better with the M4A1S in a 1v1, how could we 1v1 using only the M4A1S or some other guns (on Dust 2 or any map)?

Comment: Invite him to a lobby and start a bot match with the map you want. If you guys are ingame kick bots via console -> "bot_kick all" without quotes is the command. After that restart the match if necessary with console command -> "mp_restartgame 1" again without quotes and 1 can be changed to any number and means the number of seconds until the match restarts.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, start a multiplayer lobby and start a casual game - making sure it is **private** of course - then start the game. Go to the pause menu and vote to change the map to whatever map you desire: it should instantly change the map. Now invite your friend(s) from the pause menu or from the Steam overlay.

There are many commands to practice by yourself or with your friends in CS:GO. Most of these commands are listed here: http://www.tobyscs.com/csgo-practice-config/. For a 1v1 with a certain weapon you would *kick the bots*, increase the *starting money*, possibly enable *show impacts* or whatever you want really.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to 1v1 your friend is 1v1 servers. They allow you to pick your guns for each round so you could both pick M4A1-S. Also, they have 1v1 maps, just browse community servers and search 1v1.

Answer (score -2):

You can possibly find a empty community server or use hamachi (a networking program) and go into a bot match and kick all the bots using console and enable infinite money to buy M4A1-S every round. Also, you might want to change the maximum time limit and maximum rounds.